# open a youtube page in a webview on android 4.4+ using webchromeclient and play videos in same window

Tags: android-4.4-kitkat, webchromeclient

I am creating an android app in which I just want to load a youtube "page" of a user in a webview.
So for that there are two clients WebViewClient & WebChromeClient and to play videos we have to use WebChromeClient, but when i load the youtube page using WebChromeClient, my main activity gives me an option to open it in either chrome browser or youtube app but i want to load the page in the same webview.

NOte: It is working fine on android 4.2.2 but I am not able to make it work on 4.4+ versions

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    public static final String PAGE_URL = "http://www.youtube.com/jaambhaari";
    final Activity activity = this;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);     
        WebView webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);

        webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);   
        webview.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
        webview.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);

        webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){});        
        webview.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient(){
            public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress){
                activity.setTitle("Loading...");
                if(progress == 100){
                    activity.setTitle(R.string.app_name);
                }
            }
        });     
        webview.loadUrl(PAGE_URL);
    }
}
```

Manifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.jaambhaari.jaambhaari"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <!-- Splash screen -->
        <activity
            android:name="com.jaambhaari.jaambhaari.SplashScreen"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" /> 
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                <data android:mimeType="application/*" />
                <data android:mimeType="audio/*" />
                <data android:mimeType="image/*" />
                <data android:mimeType="message/*" />
                <data android:mimeType="multipart/*" />
                <data android:mimeType="text/*" />
                <data android:mimeType="video/*" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <!-- Main activity -->
        <activity
            android:name="com.jaambhaari.jaambhaari.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >            
        </activity>
    </application> 
</manifest>
```

**Following are the texts I get in the console when i run it on android 4.4.2 :**

1. Viewport target-densitydpi is not supported
2. FBIOGET_FSCREENINFO failed
3. Async pixel transfers not supported

Answer (score 6):

The new webview is a mess. Lot many things are broken. I wanted to add this as a comment, but dont have enough reputation. You can go through this bug report (html video support)

https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=239864

Problems are so severe, that developers are crying foul to get the old webview back 
https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=62293